# DataTable To GridView To Excel - Display errors

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, gridview, datatable

I'm working on a C# project (webform).

I get all my datas from the db in a `DataTable`.
I bind the `DataTable` to my `GridView` and export it on .xls file.

But Excel display truncate my numbers.
As you can see on the image below, the first row is what I expect to have (I click on the cell to display the full number).

[image]

How could I specify (`DataTable` or `GridView` or.. other) that I would like to display correctly my datas please ?

Comment: How are you exporting to Excel?

Comment: you could preformat cells before exporting or use a parameter to tell Excel how to interpret the data but @mason has got a good point. How are you exporting?

Comment: Yes I export to Excel.

Comment: @wytes what is the method you are using to export to excel? how are you exporting to excel? please post any of your code.